# Will subview UIView get any callback when the containing UIViewController viewWillDisappear gets called

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nstimer

I have a custom control which i have added to view of UIViewController, it has a timer in it and my requirement is to stop the timer when ViewController disappears(ie let us say new ViewController gets pushed on the stack). Right now i am manually calling one function on the custom control to stop timer in viewWillDisappear of ViewController and i want to handle it inside the custom control as it is being used at multiple places and i might use it inside something like a table view as well in future.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, maybe it is time to upgrade the control from UIView to UIViewController.  You don't need to change UIView implementation, but add a controller wrapper.

There is a container View, which can server as the Control (for the UIView) but all logic is better to move to UIViewController behind the container View, including the Timer.

When the parent ViewController is dismissed, your Controller's viewDidDisappear can also get called automatically.  This is the best way I can get now. Hope you are satisfied with this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can. 
1) Created singleton that will store the link for you class. And call his method.
2) You can created delegate for this class for you next vc. And call his method.
3) You can get vc from stack navigation controller. And call method.

Answer (score -1):

Life cycle methods of child view controller will be called, so you may stop the time in `viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` of the child view controller.

Comment: Pls do add a comment for the down vote, it really helps :)

Comment: I have not down voted it but i have mentioned in the question that i am already doing what you have mentioned. I want to handle that inside the custom view itself. Like for example lets say if i have five instances of that custom view added to the viewcontroller's view then i have to maintain references to all five of them just to stop the timer in your solution and i want to avoid that.